# When an API goes public, can an app still get rejected for using it?

Tags: ios

A co-worker and I are having a debate about how Apple treats apps that use a formerly private API. Imagine if you will `[NSAppleObject someMethod]` where `someMethod` was a private, undocumented method in iOS 7.1, but as of iOS 8.2 it gets made public. The app supports iOS 7.1 up.

I want to check for the availability of `someMethod` using `respondsToSelector` and, if available, use it. My co-worker contends that because this method was private in 7.1 and our app supports 7.1, Apple will reject its use, even though the API is now public.

Insofar as anyone can predict what Apple will and will not reject, is my co-worker correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you will not be rejected. Apple simply runs a test on your app to see what APIs it uses. If the API is public for your app's Base SDK then you are fine. The fact that the now public API was private in your app's earlier Deployment target is irrelevant.

Besides, how could Apple tell if your app is using the now public API only on devices where the API is actually public.

If Apple rejected an app for using an API that is public for your Base SDK but private for your Deployment Target, far too many apps would be rejected for trying to use updated APIs while still supporting older iOS versions. It would be a bad decision.

The bigger issue is that the formerly private API is likely to be buggier or work differently in the versions of iOS where it was private. So the actual problem to worry about is having your app avoid using the now public API in versions of iOS where it was private because the older private version may not work as well as it does in the newer versions of iOS where it is public.

Comment: Fantastic. Much better argument than anything I could come up with. As far as difference in operation of the API, that should (hopefully) be mitigated by accurate unit tests and QA.